# Google Maps marker.getPosition only uses last co-ords

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm importing map data from an XML list and placing that in markerArray, then calling createMarkers();
The markers appear on the map ok, but clicking always goes to the last marker on the list.

All help appreciated.

```
function createMarkers() {
for (i=0; i<markerArray.length; i++){
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:markerArray[i].latlng, map:map, title:markerArray[i].label, icon:images[markerArray[i].type]});
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(9);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Just a random thought: can you use map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`marker` is redefined with each loop iteration. The function bound to `'click'` should be wrapped in a closure with a local copy of `marker`. I had to do something similar once and used this:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
   (function(marker_inner) {
      return function() {
        map.setZoom(9);
        map.setCenter(marker_inner.getPosition());
      }
   })(marker)
 );
```

Comment: That certainly works, as does (this.getPosition). The latter seems a more elegant solution, or am I missing something?

Comment: In the code I took the snippet above from, there was a bit more going on ... `this` is sufficient for what you're trying to do, but I guess I just like closures ;)

Comment: Thanks. Does this also work for infoWindow data?

Comment: Use the closure method for setting infoWindow data.